# how to Select Null in LINQ - SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have use `T-SQL query` and I am trying to rewrite it in `Linq`.

This is the T-SQL query

```
Select NULL 
From Users U
inner join Porducts P on U.ProductId=P.ProductId
Where U.CreatedDate >= '2021-01-01'
```

And this one is my LINQ query

```
var queryResult= from u in _context.Users
                 join p in _context.Products on u.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                 where u.CreatedDate >= new DateTime(2021,01,01)
                 select (???);
```

I don't know how to write `select null` in the `select` part of LINQ.

Comment: select new {null} ?

Comment: Question why would you select null? perhaps you just need Count()?

Comment: So what will be the output of this query?

Comment: I would guess `select (object)null`, but why on earth does someone need this? If you need the number of entries, you should use `.Count()`.

Comment: Since it can't defer the output type because all it knows it returns `null` you'll have to specify the generic type parameters: `.Select<User, object>(_ => null);`. Change `User` to whatever type comes in and `object` if you need any specific output type.

Comment: Actually, the SQL query in a function, if the query exists function returns 1, else return 0. I am trying to write this function in c#. That's why I need the `select null`. It is weird, I know but someone constructed the function before.

Comment: Why not use `.Any()` to determine if there is any result or not? (I assume that counts as "query exists")

Comment: You can also use `select 0` and then call `.Any() ? 1 : 0` on it.

Comment: The thing is you can write `select u).Any()` and it will not ask for u the whole user. It will translate into an exist. You don't have to select null to save some performance here.

Comment: @simoncare post the entire code then. Or just don't convert the function to LINQ and and configure your ORM to use it. LINQ is a query language for an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. The main reason people use SQL functions is because they can be included in queries and act like parameterized views. You can't replicate that in LINQ.

Comment: BTW if you have to use JOINs in LINQ it means the entities are missing relations and navigation properties. If you configure your model properly, LINQ itself would generate the JOIN.